# How to persist DropDownList[] array property in view state

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a DropDownList[] property and get-set values from view state (purpose is to retain the dynamic dropdownlist values during post back, all these dynamic dropdowns have selectedindexchanged event associated), my code is as below:

```
    private DropDownList[] MyDDLArray
    {
        get
        {
            var value = ViewState["MyDDLArray"];
            return (DropDownList[])value;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["MyDDLArray"] = value;
        }
    }
```

when I am initialing a value like:

```
 MyDDLArray[0] = new DropDownList();
```

I am getting error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You are accessing two different keys: `MyDDLArray` and `SelectedUser`. Why don't you try using `MyDDLArray` in setter? :)

Comment: @Nino was a typo while posting my question, still no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

To resolve your problem, you simply need to handle null values:

```
private DropDownList[] MyDDLArray
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["MyDDLArray"] == null) ViewState["MyDDLArray"] = new DropDownList[limit];
        return (DropDownList[])ViewState["MyDDLArray"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["MyDDLArray"] = value;
    }
}
```

On a side note, Arrays are not good unless you have fixed number of items. Consider a `List` in the other case where you don't have the hassle of resizing the array.